# Ruby on Rails install on M1 Macbook Air (added photo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apple-m1

[image]I'm trying to install rails. Setup: M1 Macbook Air and Rails 2.6.8
So far my progress is:

```
cd rainbow
bundle install
rake db:setup
```

Then I get error messages:

[image: screenshot of stack trace]

Comment: Try to follow this article - https://medium.com/@vishalsadriya1224/how-to-install-postgresql-node-with-nvm-ruby-with-chruby-rails-in-macbook-pro-m1-chip-4612e0a50260

Comment: Are you sure its rails -v 2.6.8?. It looks, its ruby version. Can you specify full error logs.

Comment: Please don't just add screenshots of code or errors. Instead, please copy the actual errors and and code you have into the question itself. Screenshots are not accessible, often incomplete, are not read by search engines and are generally painful to work with. You can still do this by clicking in the **Edit** link below your question and replace the screenshots with the full errors.

Answer (score 0):

Trying commenting out bootsnap in your Gemfile.

```
# gem 'bootsnap'
```

Then run `bundle install` again.